# Some Unicode characters not appearing

Tags: c#, text, unicode, symbols

I'm trying to replicate (not an exact replica) the CharMap program from windows in my program for inserting and adding symbols. Problem is that the symbols would work on a machine with Windows 7, 8 10 but some symbols wouldn't show on Windows XP.

**Windows XP**

[image: Windows XP]

**Windows 7, 8, 10**

[image]

I'm currently using the below to generate my symbols:

```
public static string CharToHex(char c)
{
   return ((ushort)c).ToString("X4");
}

string x = CharToHex(Convert.ToChar(defaultSymbolsCollection[i]));
int value = int.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string symbol = char.ConvertFromUtf32(value).ToString();
AddSymbol(Convert.ToString((char)value);


Void AddSymbol(string _symbolText)
{
   Button symbolButton = new Button()
   {
      Text = _symbolText,
      Size = new Size(32, 32),
      Font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 9),
      Tag = _symbolText,
      UseMnemonic = false,
   };

   symbolButton.Click += SymbolButton_Click;
   pnl_SymbolHolder.Controls.Add(symbolButton);
}
```

This ends up working only on Windows 7, 8, 10 but not on Windows XP. some symbols don't show, instead is represented by a square and others do.

How do I go about solving this problem? my other alternative was to draw the symbols at the center of the button that way it's always there regardless because it was drawn but I would like to see other alternatives, perhaps a solution to this problem

Comment: Your code sample sets the button text to `_symbolText` which isn't defined in the code?

Comment: @stuartd fixed. It's inside a void addSymbol() which takes the string _symbol

Comment: Is Arial Unicode MS installed on the XP machines? It is very commonly found, but not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

The font "Arial Unicode MS" is not included with Windows XP/7/8/10, but is included with [some Microsoft Office products](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081). Windows XP is likely using "Tahoma" instead (the default UI font), which [does not](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1131) include glyphs for those symbols (whereas "Segoe UI", the default UI font on Windows 7/8/10, [does](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1941)).

For the characters to appear correctly, you will need to find/install/use a font that has glyphs for those characters.